# Add border to a line element of d3js

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I am trying to add a black border to a line element of the d3js library. How can I do that ? I tried it with following Code:

Plunker:https://plnkr.co/edit/brSPxoRczQcULz3IxXQk?p=preview

CSS:

```
<style>
   line.linecap {
   border-style:dashed;
   border-width:2px;
   border-color: black;
  }
</style>
```

JavaScript

```
<script>
var line = d3.select("body") 
      .append("svg")  
      .attr("width", 449)     
      .attr("height", 249); 



line.append("line")     
    .style("stroke", "rgb(220, 220, 220)")  
    .attr("stroke-width", 94)
    .classed('linecap', true)
    .attr("x1", 139)
    .attr("y1", 487)      
    .attr("x2", 139)    
    .attr("y2", 92);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SVG elements don't have *border*. Please check this list: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/propidx.html

That being said, the simple alternative is making another line, with the colour you want, a little bit thicker:

```js
var line = d3.select("body") 
          .append("svg")  
          .attr("width", 500)     
          .attr("height", 300); 

    line.append("line")     
        .style("stroke", "red")  
        .attr("stroke-width", 96)
        .classed('linecap', true)
        .attr("x1", 139)
        .attr("y1", 291)      
        .attr("x2", 139)    
        .attr("y2", 9);

    line.append("line")     
        .style("stroke", "rgb(220, 220, 220)")  
        .attr("stroke-width", 94)
        .classed('linecap', true)
        .attr("x1", 139)
        .attr("y1", 290)      
        .attr("x2", 139)    
        .attr("y2", 10);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can draw a rectangle ([SVG `rect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/rect)) instead of a line, then border is available using `stroke`.

```
line.append("rect")     
    .style("stroke-width", "3")
    .style("fill", "none")
    .style("stroke", "rgb(220, 220, 220)") 
    .attr("x", 139)
    .attr("y", 92)      
    .attr("width", 94)    
    .attr("height", 487 - 92 );
```

[Updated plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/hChjuuvAxGjQULatWgAp?p=preview)

P.S. the line drawn gets outside of the svg boundaries, I didn't fix this problem (to do so, just adjust the coordinates as wanted).